# Is there a way of extracting float values from a python dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm new to Python so I'm still struggling with a lot of simple things.
I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
<class 'dict'>
{'1388534400000': {'electricity': 0.0}, '1388538000000': {'electricity': 0.0}, '1388541600000': {'electricity': 0.0},...}
```

I want my final output to be the sum of the float values of 'electricity' but the first key `('1388534400000', '1388538000000',...)` changes. How do I do that in python considering dictionaries are not indexable?
I got this dictionary from a json file after extracting the information from a website and extracting it from another dictionary that had 2 subsets: 'metadata' and 'data'.

I have tried `dictionary.values()` but it returns a dict_values containing the pairs 'electricity' and the respective float value.

This is the code I'm using:

```
r = s.get(url, params=args)
packages_json = r.json()
print(packages_json)
print(type(packages_json))
package_json = packages_json['data']
print(type(package_json))
print(package_json)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, you will always have a key `electricity` in the values, you could just `sum` the value of `electricity` like,

```
>>> d
{'1388534400000': {'electricity': 0.0}, '1388538000000': {'electricity': 0.0}, '1388541600000': {'electricity': 0.0}}
>>> sum(v['electricity'] for k,v in d.items())
0.0
```

or just,

```
>>> sum(v['electricity'] for v in d.values())
0.0
```

And, maybe use the latter, because i did a benchmark,

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(v['electricity'] for k,v in d.items())", setup="d={'1388534400000': {'electricity': 0.0}, '1388538000000': {'electricity': 0.0}, '1388541600000': {'electricity': 0.5}}")
0.4952311920005741
>>> timeit.timeit("sum(v['electricity'] for v in d.values())", setup="d={'1388534400000': {'electricity': 0.0}, '1388538000000': {'electricity': 0.0}, '1388541600000': {'electricity': 0.5}}")
0.4470630470004835
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sum = 0
for key in dict:
    try:
        dict[key] + 2.04
        sum += dict[key]
    except TypeError:
        pass
```